# Exponiendo DbContext como propiedad de una unidad de trabajo, seria esto correcto C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Tengo una unidad de trabajo, la cual tiene una serie de repositorios, pero en ciertos caso no quiero hacer un repositorio para tablas básicas en las que no necesito mayor cosas, cual seria la manera correcta de manejar esto...
Estoy utilizando EF Core

tengo lo siguiente, mi código es totalmente genérico y he usado los dos patrones Repositorios junto con la unidad de trabajo, en efecto tengo mi repositorio genérico y a su vez tengo la unidad de trabajo que se ve similar a esto...

```
public partial class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
        private readonly AppDbContext _contaContext;
        public IAlgoRepository Algo { get; }

        public UnitOfWork(AppDbContext contaContext)
        {
           _contaContext = contaContext;
           Algo = new AlgoRepository (contaContext);
        }
        public bool Complete()
        {
            //TODO
        }
        public async Task<bool> CompleteAsync()
        {
           //TODO;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
          //TODO
        }
     }
```

Entonces mi idea es exponer el DbContext así no necesito crear un repositorio por cada tabla de la base datos.

Answer (score 0):

No seria correcto que exponieras tu `DbContext` ya que esto crearía mucha dependencia del mismo y no tienes forma de asegurar que siempre utilizaras EF.

Intenta creando un repositorio genérico que contenga las operaciones básicas que reciba una un tipo `T`, siento `T` la entidad:

```
public class SimpleRepository<T> where T : class
{
   private DbSet<T> set;
   public SimpleResository(DbContext context)
   {
     set = context.Set<T>();
   }

   public T GetById(int id) => this.set.Find(id);

   public IQueryable<T> GetAll() => this.set.AsQueryable();

   // agrega los metodos generios que necesites

}
```

Entonces su uso seria:

```
var personasRepository = new SimpleRepository<Persona>();
var juan = personasRepository.GetById(24);

var miBarrio = personasRepository.GetAll().Where(x=>x.CodigoBarrio == 44);
```

Asi no tendrias que exponer el contexto  para consultas en un modelo o clase DTO.

Recuerda que la clase `T` debe de estar definido en el contexto.

Comment: Te agradezco que te hayas tomando el tiempo para responder la duda @Einer muchas gracias.